# The install of meteor was NOT successful using CHOCOLATEY. [METEORJS]

Tags: meteor, chocolatey

I am trying to install latest Meteor 1.6 using Chocolatey on windows.

My Windows configurations is

> Processor - core i7, 2nd gen, 2.2 Ghz
>
> RAM - 8 GB,
>
> System Type - 64 bit

I also used below command in COMMAND PROMPT to start with installation,

```
choco install meteor -y --execution-timeout 10000
```

still I am facing below issue.

```
meteor v0.0.2 [Approved]

meteor package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.

Downloading meteor 64 bit
  from 'https://packages.meteor.com/bootstrap-link?arch=os.windows.x86_64'
  
Progress: 4% - Saving 8.12 MB of 171.74 MB

Download of meteor-bootstrap-os.windows.x86_64.tar.gz (171.74 MB) completed.

ERROR: Chocolatey expected a file at 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\
meteor\0.0.2\meteor-bootstrap-os.windows.x86_64.tar.gz' to be of length '180086547' but the length was '8552029'.

The install of meteor was NOT successful.

Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\meteor\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - meteor (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\meteo r\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Comment: Did you use ad cmd with lifted permission?

Comment: What does it even mean?

Comment: Open the cmd / shell as administrator

Comment: i opened it as administrator, it is so slow installation, I can't even imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest do not use Windows **CMD**, better use **Power Shell** and the issue will be resolved.

Chocolatey is behaving very strange as you can see my question with error log.

Below is the success I got using Power Shell

[image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there should be no difference between doing this in CMD or PowerShell.  I have just successfully installed the meteor package through the CMD shell.

Comment: I understand that as well, but I got it done only using Powershell

Answer (score 0):

I have just attempted the installation of the meteor package on my own virtual machine, and I can tell you that the installation was indeed successful.

Looking at the log, it would appear that the download of the tar.gz did not complete successfully, and as a result, the file is not the same size as it was expected based on the response headers.

Best advice would be to try the installation again.

Comment: Doing it 3rd time and why even it is happening?

Comment: @Ankur Soni Maybe you add some specs of your Windows system (Windows Version, build # if possible, 32 or 64 bit etc.) I blurry remember some issues related to certain specs but no promise on that.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Done! Modified question.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (same error message while installing meteor 1.6 on windows cmd shell runnning in admin mode) until i tried installing with powershell running in admninistrator mode and suspending windows defender. Hope this helps.

Comment: Add more detail in your ans

Comment: @HassanUsman  what I meant is that installation is nor working properly on windows cmd, instead use Powershell on administrator mode, with windows defender suspended. If I didn't specify more is because the environment in which the problem appeared is very much the same that in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the timeout value about 100000. This will at least save you from the occasional termination of the download process due to maybe changes in internet speeds.